# Error in start up MATLAB 2014a (32bit)

Tags: matlab, java-native-interface

After setting up the program ,I meet a fatal error on Startup matlab .As following :

***Failed to start the Java Virtual machine - JNI error: -3***

I want to know where is error and how to solve it .Please help me ,Thanks !

PS: My OS is windows 7 (32bit) ，and jdk 1.8(32bit) is set up successfully  (Certainly PATH and CLASSPATH is set OK).

Comment: Is the `matlab_java` environment variable set? If so try deleting it. Matlab should run with the bundled JRE, setting this variable configures matlab to use another java version which may cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch the application, does that error display in a dialog box, or within the MATLAB console? Does MATLAB launch if you use the '-nojvm' flag (in your shortcut path or from within a Command Prompt window)? If not, does it launch if you use a '-nodisplay' flag?

Definitely make sure you don't have a 'matlab_java' environment variable set, and if you are able to launch MATLAB, you should run the following commands:

```
>> rehash toolboxcache; 
>> restoredefaultpath;
>> savepath;
```

After running the commands, restart MATLAB. When MATLAB launches, do you still see the error?

If you aren't able to get MATLAB to run, can you look within your %temp% directory for an error log? I don't recall the specific naming convention, but you should be able to find it based on it's timestamp.

Hope this helps, and if it doesn't, try calling the MathWorks Installation and Licensing team. As long as you have a real license, they'll help you.

*Disclaimer: I'm a former member of the recommended team above, but have no current affiliation with MathWorks.*

Comment: Re-installing it is Okay after deleting 'matlab_java' .